# How To validate Formsets in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views, django-1.11

I am new to `Django FormSet`, let say I have the form like follow.

```
class PillarForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
      model = Pillar
      exclude = ("created_at", "updated_at", "is_active", "owner")
PillarFormSet = formset_factory(PillarForm, validate_min=True)
```

and my pillar model looks like follow

```
class Pillar(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  description = models.TextField(null=True)
  order = models.IntegerField()

  #SYSTEM FIELDS
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  report = models.ForeignKey(Report, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

when  my views look like follow

```
def pillars_create(request, report_id):
  context = {}
  report = Report.objects.get(pk=report_id, is_active=True)
  form = PillarFormSet()
  if request.POST:
    form = PillarFormSet(request.POST)
    print(form.errors)
  return render(request, os.path.join(TEMPLATE_FOLDER, "create/index.html"), 
  { 'report' : report, 'formset' : form })
```

but form doesn't showing the error messages for example `name`, `order` are required fields but it doesn't shows the error messages and `form.is_valid` is `True`, what mistake i made here.

but if I create `formset` with fields `max_fields`, `min_fields`, 'validate_max' like it shows the message.

```
PillarFormSet = formset_factory(PillarForm, max_num=5, min_num=4, validate_max=True, validate_min=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some googling i found, By default `formsets` doesn't validate all forms inside it. so i create `CustomFormSet` by extending the `BaseFormSet` like follow

```
class PillarRequiredFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(PillarRequiredFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       for form in self.forms:
         form.empty_permitted = False
```

and pass the `customformset` as `kwargs`,when creating model formset like follow.

```
PillarModelFormSet = modelformset_factory(Pillar, form=PillarForm, formset=PillarRequiredFormSet, extra=3)
```

and set the `empty_permitted` to false,  so validation works fine.